# Pull/Scrape data which has multiple results page VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to create a macro in excel so that i can scrape the data from a website which has multiple results pages. I cannot seem to figure it out. I can only get the information to show from page one, but as duplicate, as i have tried to code it to go to the next page. That is why i was getting the results to duplicate. Here is the code that i have so far.

```
Sub QueryDelinquency()
Dim nextrow As Integer, i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
For i = 1 To 5 'this is the page range to be captured.
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Page " & i
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=&i &county_1=AL&status=NS&send_date=12/11/2015&search_1.x=1" & i, _
        Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))


        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "10"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Save
Next
i = i + 1
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

I want it to pull all of the data. This particular search on the website i know has well over 60 results pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let's say that there are 100 pages in this search result. If there is a way to get the pages part in the url to keep counting until it reaches the end of the data, that is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=AL&status=NS&send_date=12/11/2015&search_1.x=1", _
            Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))
```

Comment: I swear I tried that same code earlier, but I was receiving a syntax error. Thank you. I have been trying to think/code a way for this to continue on til the last page. This may be a different number each time it is ran, so i was wondering if there is a way for this to pull all information until the last page?

Comment: I haven't studied the page, but guess you don't get the number of pages identified in the results.  If you do, just use this value.  So what happens on the last page?  Do you just stop getting the next page arrow icon?  Maybe you can check to see if that icon exists, or, if it does, check the URL of it to see if it matches the one you are already on. At any rate as a last resort, I suppose you could query the first and last items of the results and see if they match the just prior results to create a break condition from the loop.

Comment: On the last page, there is no next icon to click on. The only buttons you can click on the last page is the previous page icon and a new search icon. But the new search is always on the page regardless. But i guess i could actually use a Do While statement rather than using a for loop. Correct me if i am wrong, but if lets say i set the limit for the Do While loop to 100, and the last page is 70, it should stop the search at 70 and not try to continue on until it gets to 100 correct? Also, do you know of a way to scrape just the header columns only from page 1 rather than from every page?

Comment: Here's another link that may help: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/809589-excel-visual-basic-applications-scrape-data-series-web-pages.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's ok. I actually have a filter being created so what i will do is just filter out those results for the heading. it's no big deal. thank you though for all of your help. i only have one more problem to fix out and hopefully it won't be too difficult. it's when there is no more data to scrape, it pulls in this data saying no more delinquency information x amount of times it does that. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Maybe just throw in an Exit Sub if it returns that error, something like If Error "whatever error it is" Then Exit Sub

Comment: It's not really an error, it is just not finding anymore data to scrape and adds "No Delinquency Found" as the information. I am not sure how to really go abouts in writing the code for this. I understand what you are saying, but i do not know how to put this into play

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like each page uses almost exactly the same URL, just the page=&I changes to page=2&,page=3&, and so on, so you could either use a counter to increment the URL and loop through all of the pages until there aren't any left, or have it click the right arrow button to go to the next page and have it scrape that as found in the html:

```
<a href="pleaseWait_Portal.asp?redirectto=delinquency_results.asp&amp;SID=&amp;county_1=&amp;status=NS&amp;send_date=12/11/2015&amp;page=4&amp;search_1.x=1"><img src="portal/images/singlearrowrightbutton.gif" border="0" alt="Next"></a>
```

Also, make sure you create a date variable to replace the date in the URL or you'll just keep scraping the same day over and over again.

Comment: Since the url is basically always going to stay the same, how could i implement a counter to focus solely on just the page number? I understand what you are saying, but i'm not sure how to implement the counter.

Comment: you may find use in this link: http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/vba-to-web-scrape-multiple-urls.20974/ It's basically a compilation of all the tips here and the code you already have, showing it all put together in a loop.

Comment: Yes, that is helpful. Thank you for your help with this. Do you also know how to scrape the header just from page one? What is happening is that the column headers are grabbed on every page. I would just like for the column headers to be grabbed just once, and let the rest of the data flow on through.